# SWIFTUI = Why List of Employees in HomeView doesn't update when updated data from anotherView

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, urlsession

I'm new in Swift and I'm trying to practice URLSession in a Crud app with SwiftUI.

For my app I'm using this api request changing Users for Employees:

https://gorest.co.in/public/v1/

I use MVVM for develop this app, so I have View, ViewModel, Repository, Datasource and Model.

When I try to update data in API, this data is not updated in View... this is my code:

Models:

```
struct User: Decodable, Encodable{
    let id: Int
    var name: String?
    var email: String?
    var sex: String?

    enum Codingkeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case email
        case sex = "gender"
    }

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Codingkeys.self)
        self.id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.email = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .email)
        self.sex = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .sex)
    }
}


struct Employee: Codable {
    var data: User
}

struct Employees: Decodable{
    let users: [User]
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case data
    }
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.users = try container.decode([User].self, forKey: .data)
    }
}
```

Datasource:

```
final class EmployeeDatasource {
    private let urlBase = "https://gorest.co.in/public/v1/"
    private let token = "TOKENIMPLEMENTED"

   func updateEmployee(employee: User, completionBlock: @escaping (Result<Employee, NetworkError>) -> Void){
        guard let url = URL(string: "\(urlBase)users/\(employee.id)") else{
            completionBlock(.failure(.urlError))
            return
        }
        
        guard let jsonData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(employee) else {
            completionBlock(.failure(.encodingError))
            return
        }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "PUT"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.httpBody = jsonData
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                completionBlock(.failure(.transportError(error)))
                return
            }
            
            if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, !(200...299).contains(response.statusCode){
                completionBlock(.failure(.serverError(statusCode: response.statusCode)))
                return
            }
            
            guard let data = data else {
                completionBlock(.failure(.noData))
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let employeeDataModel = try JSONDecoder().decode(Employee.self, from: data)
                completionBlock(.success(employeeDataModel))
            } catch {
                completionBlock(.failure(.decodingError(error)))
                return
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
final class EmployeeRepository{
    func updateEmployee(employee: User, completionBlock: @escaping (Result<Employee, NetworkError>) -> Void){
        employeesDatasource.updateEmployee(employee: employee, completionBlock: completionBlock)
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
final class EmployeesViewModel: ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var employees: [User] = []
    @Published var messageError: String?
    @Published var alertError: Bool = false
    
    private let employeesRepository: EmployeeRepository
    
    init(employeeRepository: EmployeeRepository = EmployeeRepository()){
        self.employeesRepository = employeeRepository

   func updateEmployee(employee: User){
        employeesRepository.updateEmployee(employee: employee) {[weak self] result in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                switch result {
                case .success(let success):
//TODO
                    
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(String(describing: error))
                    switch error{
                    case .decodingError(_):
                        self?.messageError = "Error generando la decodificacion de la data \(error.localizedDescription)"
                    case .encodingError:
                        self?.messageError = "Error generando la codificacion de la data \(error.localizedDescription)"
                    case .noData:
                        self?.messageError = "Error con la data \(error.localizedDescription)"
                    case .serverError(let statusCode):
                        self?.messageError = "Error del servidor \(statusCode), \(error.localizedDescription)"
                    case .transportError(_):
                        self?.messageError = "Error del transporte de la peticion \(error.localizedDescription)"
                    case .unknownedError(_):
                        self?.messageError = "Error desconocido \(error.localizedDescription)"
                    case .urlError:
                        self?.messageError = "Error con la creación de la url \(error.localizedDescription)"
                    }
                    self!.alertError = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HomeView:

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @StateObject var employeesViewModel = EmployeesViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                List(employeesViewModel.employees, id: \.id) { employee in
                    NavigationLink {

                        UpdateEmployee(employeesViewModel: employeesViewModel, employee: employee)
                    } label: {
                        Text("\(employee.name ?? "No name")")
                    }
                    .swipeActions(edge: .leading) {
                        Button {
                            employeesViewModel.deleteEmployee(employee: employee)
                        } label: {
                            Label("Borrar", systemImage: "trash.fill")
                        }
                        .tint(.red)

                    }

                
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Empleados")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    HStack {
                        NavigationLink(destination: CreateEmployeeView()) {
                            Image(systemName: "plus")

                        }
                    }

                }

            }
            
        }
                    
        .onAppear{
            employeesViewModel.getEmployees()
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $employeesViewModel.alertError) {
            Alert(
                title: Text("Error"),
                message: Text(employeesViewModel.messageError?.description ?? "Error"),
                primaryButton: .default(
                    Text("Try Again"),
                    action: employeesViewModel.getEmployees
                ),
                secondaryButton: .destructive(
                    Text("Cancel")
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

UpdateEmployeeView:

```
struct UpdateEmployee: View {
    //    1. Manejo de viewModel con EnvironmentObject (Diferente a StateObject)
    //    @EnvironmentObject var employeesViewModel : EmployeesViewModel
    @ObservedObject var employeesViewModel : EmployeesViewModel
    var employee: User
    @State var name = ""
    @State var correo = ""
    @State var genero = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            VStack{
                Text("Nombre")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                
                TextField("Nombre", text: $name)
                    .frame(maxHeight: 45)
                    .border(Color.gray, width: 0.5)
                    .padding([.horizontal, .bottom, .top], 30)
            }
            VStack{
                Text("Correo")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                TextField("Correo", text: $correo)
                    .frame(maxHeight: 45)
                    .border(Color.gray, width: 0.5)
                    .padding([.horizontal, .bottom, .top], 30)
            }
            VStack{
                Text("Genero")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                
                TextField("Genero", text: $genero)
                    .frame(maxHeight: 45)
                    .border(Color.gray, width: 0.5)
                    .padding([.horizontal, .bottom, .top], 30)
            }
            
            Button {
                self.employeesViewModel.updateEmployee(employee: User(id: employee.id, name: name, email: correo, sex: genero))
            } label: {
                Text("Actualizar")
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .onAppear{
            self.name = employee.name ?? ""
            self.correo = employee.email ?? ""
            self.genero = employee.sex ?? "" 

        }
        .alert(isPresented: $employeesViewModel.alertError) {
            Alert(
                title: Text("Error"),
                message: Text(employeesViewModel.messageError?.description ?? "Error"),
                primaryButton: .default(
                    Text("Try Again"),
                    action: employeesViewModel.getEmployees
                ),
                secondaryButton: .destructive(
                    Text("Cancel")
                )
            )
        }
        
    }
}
```

'
Thanks for your answers, if you see details to improve, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

kind of an open question you have here, also you have a few things wrong, Here is a working example:

1. I added the async/await for request so you have newer way to make a request.
2. There is no need for init when you use codingKeys
3. You can use a `@Binding` to load the detail view
4. I don't have a bearer token so I wasn't able to use the endpoint but I left you a local update.

Take a look

```
  import Foundation
            import SwiftUI


            enum NetworkError: Error {
                case transportError(Error)
                case urlError
                case encodingError
                case serverError(statusCode: Int)
                case noData
                case decodingError(Error)
            }

            struct User: Codable, Identifiable {
                let id: Int
                var name: String?
                var email: String?
                var sex: String?
                
                enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                    case id
                    case name
                    case email
                    case sex = "gender"
                }
            }


            struct Employee: Codable {
                var data: [User]
            }


            final class EmployeeRepository{
                
                let employeesDatasource = EmployeeDatasource()
                
                func updateEmployee(employee: User, completionBlock: @escaping (Result<User, NetworkError>) -> Void){
                    employeesDatasource.updateEmployee(employee: employee, completionBlock: completionBlock)
                }
                
                func getEmployees() async throws -> [User] {
                    
                    let requestResponse = try await employeesDatasource.getEmployees()
                    return requestResponse.data
                }
            }

            final class EmployeeDatasource {
                private let urlBase = "https://gorest.co.in/public/v1/"
                private let token = "TOKENIMPLEMENTED"
                
                func getEmployees() async throws -> Employee {
                    guard let url = URL(string: "\(urlBase)users/") else {
                        throw NetworkError.urlError
                    }
                    
                    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
                    request.httpMethod = "GET"
                    
                    let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
                    let responseData = response as! HTTPURLResponse
                    
                    if(responseData.statusCode == 200) {
                        let parsedResponseBody = try JSONDecoder().decode(Employee.self, from: data)
                        
                        return parsedResponseBody
                    }
                    else {
                        throw NetworkError.noData
                    }
                }
                
                func updateEmployee(employee: User, completionBlock: @escaping (Result<User, NetworkError>) -> Void){
                    guard let url = URL(string: "\(urlBase)users/\(employee.id)") else{
                        completionBlock(.failure(.urlError))
                        return
                    }
                    
                    guard let jsonData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(employee) else {
                        completionBlock(.failure(.encodingError))
                        return
                    }
                    
                    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
                    request.httpMethod = "PUT"
                    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                    request.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
                    request.httpBody = jsonData
                    
                    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                        if let error = error {
                            completionBlock(.failure(.transportError(error)))
                            return
                        }
                        
                        if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, !(200...299).contains(response.statusCode){
                            completionBlock(.failure(.serverError(statusCode: response.statusCode)))
                            return
                        }
                        
                        guard let data = data else {
                            completionBlock(.failure(.noData))
                            return
                        }
                        
                        do {
                            let employeeDataModel = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data)
                            completionBlock(.success(employeeDataModel))
                        } catch {
                            completionBlock(.failure(.decodingError(error)))
                            return
                        }
                    }.resume()
                }
            }

            @MainActor
            final class EmployeesViewModel: ObservableObject{
                
                @Published var employees: [User] = []
                @Published var messageError: String?
                @Published var alertError: Bool = false
                
                private let employeesRepository = EmployeeRepository()
                
                init( ) {
                    getEmployees()
                }
                
                func getEmployees () {
                    Task {
                        do {
                            employees = try await employeesRepository.getEmployees()
                        }
                        catch {
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                func updateEmployee(employee: User) {
                    employeesRepository.updateEmployee(employee: employee) {[weak self] result in
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            switch result {
                            case .success(let employee):
                                
                                if let foundIndex = self?.employees.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == employee.id}) {
                                    self?.employees[foundIndex] = employee
                                }
                                
                            case .failure(let error):
                                print(String(describing: error))
                                switch error{
                                case .decodingError(_):
                                    self?.messageError = "Error generando la decodificacion de la data \(error.localizedDescription)"
                                case .encodingError:
                                    self?.messageError = "Error generando la codificacion de la data \(error.localizedDescription)"
                                case .noData:
                                    self?.messageError = "Error con la data \(error.localizedDescription)"
                                case .serverError(let statusCode):
                                    self?.messageError = "Error del servidor \(statusCode), \(error.localizedDescription)"
                                case .transportError(_):
                                    self?.messageError = "Error del transporte de la peticion \(error.localizedDescription)"
                                case .urlError:
                                    self?.messageError = "Error con la creación de la url \(error.localizedDescription)"
                                }
                                self!.alertError = true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            struct HomeView: View {
                @StateObject var employeesViewModel = EmployeesViewModel()
                var body: some View {
                    
                    NavigationView{
                        VStack{
                            List($employeesViewModel.employees) { $employee in
                                NavigationLink {
                                    
                                    UpdateEmployee(employeesViewModel: employeesViewModel, employee: $employee)
                                } label: {
                                    Text("\(employee.name ?? "No name")")
                                }
                                .swipeActions(edge: .leading) {
                                    Button {
                                        //  employeesViewModel.deleteEmployee(employee: employee)
                                    } label: {
                                        Label("Borrar", systemImage: "trash.fill")
                                    }
                                    .tint(.red)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .navigationTitle("Empleados")
                        .toolbar {
                            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                                //                    HStack {
                                //                        NavigationLink(destination: CreateEmployeeView()) {
                                //                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                                //
                                //                        }
                                //                    }
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .onAppear{
                        employeesViewModel.getEmployees()
                    }
                    .alert(isPresented: $employeesViewModel.alertError) {
                        Alert(
                            title: Text("Error"),
                            message: Text(employeesViewModel.messageError?.description ?? "Error"),
                            primaryButton: .default(
                                Text("Try Again"),
                                action: { employeesViewModel.getEmployees() }
                            ),
                            secondaryButton: .destructive(
                                Text("Cancel")
                            )
                        )
                    }
                }
            }

            struct UpdateEmployee: View {
                //    1. Manejo de viewModel con EnvironmentObject (Diferente a StateObject)
                //    @EnvironmentObject var employeesViewModel : EmployeesViewModel
                @ObservedObject var employeesViewModel : EmployeesViewModel
                @Binding var employee: User
                @State var name = ""
                @State var correo = ""
                @State var genero = ""
                
                var body: some View {
                    VStack{
                        VStack{
                            Text("Nombre")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                            
                            TextField("Nombre", text: $name)
                                .frame(maxHeight: 45)
                                .border(Color.gray, width: 0.5)
                                .padding([.horizontal, .bottom, .top], 30)
                        }
                        VStack{
                            Text("Correo")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                            TextField("Correo", text: $correo)
                                .frame(maxHeight: 45)
                                .border(Color.gray, width: 0.5)
                                .padding([.horizontal, .bottom, .top], 30)
                        }
                        VStack{
                            Text("Genero")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                            
                            TextField("Genero", text: $genero)
                                .frame(maxHeight: 45)
                                .border(Color.gray, width: 0.5)
                                .padding([.horizontal, .bottom, .top], 30)
                        }
                        
                        Button {
                            // var updatedEmployee = employee
                            employee.name = name
                            employee.email = correo
                            employee.sex = genero
                            
                            //self.employeesViewModel.updateEmployee(employee: updatedEmployee)
                        } label: {
                            Text("Actualizar Local :D")
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .onAppear{
                        self.name = employee.name ?? ""
                        self.correo = employee.email ?? ""
                        self.genero = employee.sex ?? ""
                        
                    }
                    .alert(isPresented: $employeesViewModel.alertError) {
                        Alert(
                            title: Text("Error"),
                            message: Text(employeesViewModel.messageError?.description ?? "Error"),
                            primaryButton: .default(
                                Text("Try Again"),
                                action: { employeesViewModel.getEmployees() }
                            ),
                            secondaryButton: .destructive(
                                Text("Cancel")
                            )
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
```

[image]

Comment: Guillermo, only with annotation Binding in employee variable I solved the main issue, but the implementation of async/await it's really helpful for learn, I'm going to implement changes in my code, thank you for the answer brother